# myBatis: how to return pojo with insert?

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a simple POJO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I have mapper, saving this POJO and returning ID.

```
@Insert("insert into users(username, password) values(#{user.username}, #{user.password})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
Long save(@Param("user") User user);
```

Than, service receive entity by this ID:

```
@Override
public User save(User user) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(
            mapper.findById(
                    Optional.ofNullable(mapper.save(user))
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotSavedException("Не удалось сохранить: " + user)))
    )
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotSavedException("Не удалось сохранить: " + user));
}
```

In this case, we have one request to insert entity & second - to select it from id. Costs too much.

How to return entity after inserting in one request?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to perform the select.
It's a common misunderstanding, but `@Insert` method returns the number of updated rows, not the generated key (this is how the underlying JDBC API works).
As you specified `keyProperty="id"`, the generated key is set to `id` property of the passed `User` parameter.

Note that you should specify `keyColumn` as well.
It's required since version 3.5.0.

If your service method has to return a `User`, it may look something like this.

```java
@Override
public User save(User user) {
  if (mapper.save(user) != 1) {
    // this may not happen.
    // an exception will be thrown if insert failed.
  }
  return user;
}
```

Usually, the service method just performs INSERT and the caller keeps using the original `User` instance for later operation.

The service method:

```java
@Override
public void save(User user) {
  mapper.save(user);
}
```

The class calling the service method would look like...

```java
User user = new User("John", "xyz");
service.save(user);
model.addAttribute("user", user);
...
```

Comment: than, how to reach my goal? Can you type solution?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов I have updated the answer. If it's different from what you want, I may need more details about your goal.

Comment: than, we have no ways to return entity from database?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. What is the difference between (A) `User` selected from the DB and (B) `User` parameter with `id` filled with the generated key?